# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline is exiting with ERROR: script returned exit code 123

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

**Intent**: I am writing a Jenkins Declarative pipeline to integrate JMeter test suite with JenkinsCore. At a point, jmeter.sh script is called and I generate jmeter.jtl file in xml format.
From the generated jmeter.jtl file, I want to grep a string "failure:"and copy the stdout count to a file.

**Problem**: My declarative script works finewhen there is an error count. The output file is updated with error count but the same updation is not happening when there is success scenario. Ideally the output file should be written with value 0 in success scenario.
PS: I have tried the same command in my c2c and it works fine.

My code goes below

```
**pipeline {
    agent {
    }
    stages {
        stage {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                        ./jmeter.sh  <arguments> -n -t <*.jmxFile> -l jmeter.jtl
                        find . -name "result.jtl" | xargs grep -c "failed:" result.jtl > outputFile.txt
                        cat outputFile.txt
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the line

```
find . -name "result.jtl" | xargs grep -c "failed:" result.jtl > outputFile.txt
```

First, let's clean up the code to make it more readable.

You are using `find` command to pass a path to a `result.jtl` file found to a `grep` (using `xargs`) so you should not pass the file `result.jtl` as an argument to `grep` command manually because it will effectively pass the file twice: `grep "failed:" -c result.jtl result.jtl` To avoid that you should remove the repeated occurrence of the `result.jtl` file, the line should be

```
find . -name "result.jtl" | xargs grep -c "failed:" > outputFile.txt
```

You can also use `-exec` flag passed to `find` to achieve the same avoiding spawning unnecessary `xargs` process

```
find . -name "result.jtl" -exec grep -c "failed:" {} + > outputFile.txt
```

Now, the problem is `grep` command, by design, fails (returns non-zero exit code) when it finds no matches (when your tests passed and there's no `failed:` string found in the `result.jtl`). In Jenkins pipeline, when the command executed by `sh` step fails (returns non-zero exit code) the pipeline stage will fail immediately and `sh` step will not execute all the commands after the failed one (`cat outputFile.txt` will not be executed when there are no failures found). This is why you are not seeing the updated file. You can, however, execute [`true`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/true.1.html) command in case grep fails (finds no matches) to avoid propagating error to the pipeline. This way the `sh` step will proceed and the stage will be executed successfully:

```
find . -name "result.jtl" -exec grep -c "failed:" {} + || true > outputFile.txt
```